# How to create a network with nw library when I have already created the turtles

Tags: netlogo

I have tryied to generate a network usign nw library from Netlogo, like: nw:generate-preferential-attachment
All of the examples I have found starts creating the turtles, but in my model the turtles have been already created.

Comment: What kind of network do you want to create? http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#linkgroup shows what primitives NetLogo offers for creating and manipulating links